# How do I recognize a suitable surface and a unit normal vector?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> Compute the integral $\int_C y(z+1)dx+xzdy+xydz$ where $C: x=\cos \theta, y=\sin \theta, z=x^3+y^3, 0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi $.

So if I take $F(x,y,z)=y(z+1) \;i+xz\;j+xy\;k$. Then I have to compute $\int_C F.dr$.

$C$ is a closed curve. I can use stokes theorem.

Thus $\int_C F.dr=\int\int_S curl  F. n \;ds$ where $n$ is the unit normal vector on a surface bounded by $C$.

I know how to get curl $F.$But how do I recognize a suitable surface and a unit normal vector so that I can compute the RHS easily?

Answer (score 1):

Here your surface is given by $$\phi=x^3+y^3-z=\cos^3\theta+\sin^3\theta-z$$
and the unit normal vector is given by $$\hat n=\frac{\nabla \phi}{|\nabla \phi|}=\frac{3x^2 \hat i +3y^2 \hat j- \hat k}{|3x^2 \hat i +3y^2 \hat j - \hat k|}$$

Your surface looks like this:
[image]

Comment: @EpsilonDelta sorry it was my mistake. Corrected it now. Please check if it is okay.